# Multiflash session in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I need to send more than 1 session flash with cakephp, I have found some solutions how to create a for loop and put together a deal but wanted to know if there was any native function of cake for something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two days ago I wrote http://www.dereuromark.de/2014/04/21/cakephp-flash-messages-2-0/

Which basically added support for this in CakePHP1.x, and therefore also for CakePHP2.x now.
It stacks multiple messages per type, as well. Details see the [Wiki](https://github.com/dereuromark/tools/wiki/Flash-messages).

Answer (score 0):

Its really not clear what you really wants- but to create multiple flash message as on documentation-

```
// set a bad message.
$this->Session->setFlash('Something bad.', 'default', array(), 'bad');

// set a good message.
$this->Session->setFlash('Something good.', 'default', array(), 'good');
```

And on your view-

```
echo $this->Session->flash('good');
echo $this->Session->flash('bad');
```

And there is a Helper you can checkout- [MultiFlashHelper](https://www.google.com.bd/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=https://github.com/SamMousa/cakephp2-multiflash/blob/master/MultiFlash/View/Helper/MultiFlashHelper.php&ei=lPpXU_rNAceLrQeJ3YDAAQ&usg=AFQjCNFx9equdDPf1hgVj5VVWqJMpATkQg&sig2=_nazHV4YX3BSoYW841xGmg&bvm=bv.65177938,d.bmk)